# Selecting nested fields from DataFrame that are not part of a certain schema

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Let's say I have a DataFrame with this schema:

```
{
  a: IntegerType,
  b: { // nested struct
    c: StringType,
    d: IntegerType
  }
}
```

and I want to omit `d` with this other schema:

```
{
  a: IntegerType,
  b: { // nested struct
    c: StringType
  }
}
```

Is there a way to programmatically create a new DataFrame from the original that only has the columns in the second schema? If I do something like this:

```
val finalDf = df.select([col for col in otherSchema])
```

then it would still obtain `d` since `b` exists in both schemas and this only knows how to operate at the top-level column.

And similarly if I had a really complex schema where only the deepest level was changed, how would I do that? For example, original DataFrame has a schema like:

```
Array
  (Struct
    (Array
      (Struct
        (Array
          (Struct
            (a: INT, b: String)
          )
        )
      )
    )
  )
```

and I want to select only:

```
Array
  (Struct
    (Array
      (Struct
        (Array
          (Struct
            (a: INT)
          )
        )
      )
    )
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a sketch of a transform that allows you to do something like that. The idea is to select data from an input `struct` into an output `struct` according to the new target schema.

```scala
  def transformSchema[T](target: StructType)(ds: Dataset[T]): DataFrame = {
    import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{col, struct, transform}

    def toType(column: Column, currentDt: DataType, targetDt: DataType): Column = {
      (currentDt, targetDt) match {
        case (_, `currentDt`) => column
        case (StructType(currentFields), StructType(targetFields)) =>
          val columns = targetFields.toSeq.flatMap {
            case StructField(name, target, _, _) =>
              currentFields.collectFirst {
                case StructField(`name`, current, _, _) =>
                  toType(column.getField(name), current, target).as(name)
              }
          }
          struct(columns: _*)
        case (ArrayType(current, _), ArrayType(target, _)) =>
          transform(column, toType(_, current, target))

        // Note: Cases to handle incompatible target schemas are missing here
        case _ =>
          column
      }
    }

    ds
      .select(toType(struct(ds.columns.map(col): _*), ds.schema, target).as("col"))
      .select(target.fields.map(f => col("col").getField(f.name).as(f.name)): _*)
  }
```